# How to call 2 different Api in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I need to call 2 different endpoint api and fetch data from both, currently I'm only able to call each one individually.

Here is my code so far:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

 const url = 'https://allsportsapi.com/api/football/?met=Fixtures&APIkey=myapikey&from=2020-07-23&to=2020-07-24&leagueId=262';

https.get(url, function (response) {
  let body = '';
  response.on('data', function(chunk){
    body += chunk;

  });
  response.on('end', function(){
    const apiResponse = JSON.parse(body);
    const blob = apiResponse;
    const stan = apiResponse.result[0].event_home_team;
    const away_1 = apiResponse.result[0].event_away_team;
    const stadium = apiResponse.result[0].event_stadium;

    const prova = apiResponse.result[0].home_team_key;
     

    console.log('got a response: ');
    // console.log(blob);


    res.render('test', {team: stan, fuori:away_1, stadio: stadium});
  });


  }).on('error', function(e){
      console.log("Got an error: ", e);

});

  });


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

I need to call another api which is: https://gnews.io/api/v3/topics/sports?&token=

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when I call the second one and try to render in another ejs page, I get err 404  app.get('/', function(req, res) {


      const url = 'https://gnews.io/api/v3/topics/sports?&token=';
      https.get(url, function(response) {
        console.log(response.statusCode);

        response.on('data', function(data) {
        const newsData = JSON.parse(data);
        const title = newsData.articles[1].title;
      
     

         res.render('test', {homeFirst: homeContent, currentDay: day, news: title, read: font});
        });
         });
          });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) which is much better for making http requests.

Also if these requests have no dependency on each other then you can use `axios.all` as shown below

```
axios.all([
  axios.get('https://allsportsapi.com/api/football/?met=Fixtures&APIkey=myapikey&from=2020-07-23&to=2020-07-24&leagueId=262'),
  axios.get('https://gnews.io/api/v3/topics/sports?&token=')
])
.then(axios.spread((res1, res2) => {
  console.log(res1.data);
  console.log(res2.data);
}));
```